# How to use non probabilistic Hough lines?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to use the non probabilistic version of Hough lines in Opencv.

I successfully used the P version as follows:

```
    minLineLength = 1
    maxLineGap = 100
    blank_image = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img,1,np.pi/180,1,maxLineGap,minLineLength)
    for x in range(0, len(lines)):
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[x]:
            p1 = np.array([[x1,y1]])
            p2 = np.array([[x2,y2]])

            cv2.line(blank_image,(p1[0][0],p1[0][1]),(p2[0][0],p2[0][1]),255,1)
    return blank_image
```

Which produces this image:
[image]

If i instead delete the P in the function as: `cv2.HoughLines(img,1,np.pi/180,1,maxLineGap,minLineLength)`

I instead get the error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Perhaps you didn't read the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a)? For `HoughLines` the result is "Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a 2 or 3 element vector (ρ,θ) or (ρ,θ,votes) ..."

Comment: Also, `HoughLines` doesn't take the `maxLineGap` and `minLineLength` parameters.